# How to add and use mime type to my apache server

Tags: php, mime-types

I want to change my web url from www.site.com/maintenance.php?m=1 to a mime type url(as I was told) like www.site.com/maintenance/1. How do I do that on a apache localhost server?

I heard you must do something with htaccess so I want to say 2 thing about my htaccess

1. My htaccess in located in htdocs/folder/ .htaccess because I have multiple sites in my htdocs so I out every site files in a folder
2. I already have this code in my htaccess. If you're going to ask whether it's working , yes it's working I stole it from some cpanel hosting for my custom 404 error page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpeZC.jpg

And also, how do I get the value of /1 after the /maintenance/?

Thank you in advance

Comment: your trying to do url-rewrite not change mime-type

Comment: @DevZer0 is right. You can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do it.

Comment: More specifically, its mod_rewrite. There is a great cheat-sheet [here](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)

Comment: Yeah, I heard about this thing somewhere too, but how do I use it? I would really appreciate if someone make the code for me, I have read the tutorials given but I still don't understand mod rewrite. And in mod rewrite, how do I get the variable value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^maintenance/(.*)$ maintenance.php?m=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You get the value of `m` as you normally get. `$m = $_GET['m'];`

Comment: It works but it makes every content in my /folder/ becomes /folder/maintenance/. Example I have /folder/images/image.jpg and now when I click on a link that says that folder, it redirects me to /folder/maintenance/image/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is called [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), not changing [mime type](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html).

In your case, you can try this inside your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^maintenance/([0-9]+)$ maintenance.php?m=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Basically what the above means is that for every numerical values that follow "maintenance/" in your typed URL, take the number and pass it as the `m` value for "maintenance.php" script. So, in your "maintenance.php" file, you can access the value with `$_GET['m']`.

Note that if your `m` can accept anything other than numbers, or if your other files under "maintenance" folder can contain numbers only, thing gets a bit more complicated. You will then need additional rules to filter out the files you don't want to be converted to `$_GET['m']` value.